# How to pass javascript variable value to jQuery validate() submitHandler when doing ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using jQuery plugin for my validation on one ajax calls.

Currently I have this:

```
  $("#invoiceForm").validate({
    rules: {
      plateNumber: {
        required: true,
      },
      plateIssueState: {
        required: true,
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var invoice= 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "invoice",
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function() {
        },
        error: function() {
        }
      });
      return false; 
    }
  });
```

The submitHandler was able to serialize all the data from the HTML form, but this is not enough for me. I need to also send the variable `invoice` to the back-end however `invoice` variable is not in the `form`. I have tried to do something like this but failed, it will not in the correct JSON data format:

```
data: JSON.stringify({invoiceData:invoice, formData:form}),
```

How can I change this?

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: @SandeepNayak not errors per se, it is the JSON data not in the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your invoice value ist just a single variable, you could append it to the `data` string:

```
$("#invoiceForm").validate({
  rules: {
    plateNumber: {
      required: true,
    },
    plateIssueState: {
      required: true,
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    var invoice= 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999);
    var formData = $(form).serializeArray().map(function(obj) {
        var o = {};
        o[obj.name] = obj.value;
        return o;
    });
    var data = {
        formData: formData,
        invoiceData: invoice
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "invoice",
      data: JSON.stringify(data), // Send the concatenated values
      success: function() {
      },
      error: function() {
      }
    });
    return false; 
  }
});
```

Comment: I was expecting a more elegant way of doing this, but this does work. However I am getting the incorrect `JSON` format data, something like this:`hiddenInvoiceNum=37455038&licensePlateNumber=1234&licensePlateIssueState=AL`, thoughts?

Comment: I am getting `JSON` data like this:`{"formData":[{"name":"hiddenCusID","value":"2"},{"name":"hiddenCompanyID","value":"1"}`, however what I want is key-value pair, like this `{"formData":["hiddenCusID":"2"]}`, can you give some advise?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the invoice variable along with your form, you simply need to include an invoice input field. This can be a hidden field that gets populated just before your serialize your form data.

Assuming your have something like:

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" id="InvoiceData" />
```

You would then just add that data directly:

javascript:

```
var invoice = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999);
$('#InvoiceData').val(invoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
data: $(form).serialize() + '&invoiceData=' + JSON.stringify(invoice),
dataType:'json',
...
```